# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting - cell/text colours based on value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a query regarding conditional formatting in Excel 2010. I have a date in cell `P2`.

The function I would like is:

In cell `Q2` if a date is entered that is 7+ days after the date in cell `P2`, the colour of the cell (or text) changes to red.

How may I achieve this?

I have tried entering the conditional format for `Q2` as

```
 =DATE(YEAR(P2),MONTH(P2),DAY(P2)+7)
```

to no avail.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: try `=Q2=DATE(YEAR(P2),MONTH(P2),DAY(P2)+7)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the formula below to accomplish this.

```
=Q2>(P2+7)
```

This will compare `Q2` with the date in `P2` plus 7 days. If it is greater than 7 days past `P2`, it returns true and changes the fill.

[image]